# SOAP MTOM calls with Python

Tags: python, soap, suds, mtom

I'm currently working on a `web toolkit` in python and I have to make a lot of SOAP calls. Unfortunately for me, a couple of those calls use `MTOM`. I'm currently using `SUDS` and I would like to know if it's possible to do MTOM calls with it (I can't find anything in the documentation, so I think the answer is no).

If SUDS is not the solution, are there any alternatives?

Comment: Spyne used to have mtom support, but it stagnated as it lacked tests. You may want to have a look at it. I'd be happy to merge your work if you get it to work.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems Spyne is a server library. I need to make calls as client :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of this screenshot, it looks like it is not supported.
[image: fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/248 "Has this something to do with mtom not being supported?]